# Add multiple elements to a single var and detect if any of those are clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that can have one of three possible elements. I would like to assign whatever element exists to a var and then check if the var is clicked.
I tried using the add(), but it has confused me:

```
var testingVar = $('#element-one').find('.object').add('#element-two').find('.object').add('#element-three').find('.object');

$(testingVar ).click(function() {
   alert('works');
});
```

It seems to me that the add() overwrites the previous add()? if I am on a page that has #element-three, it works, if on a page with element-one or element-two, it doesn't. If I change the var to

```
var testingVar = $('#element-one').find('.object');
```

Then a page with element-one works.

Can someone help me understand how to use the add() properly in this case?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
$('#element-one .object').add('#element-two .object').add('#element-three .object');
```

`.find()` returns a new jquery object.

However, I think this would be easier in this case:

```
$('#element-one .object, #element-two .object, #element-three .object');
```

Or even easier, if you can change markup, is to give each element you're currently selecting by id a common class, and do this:

```
$('.common-class .object')
```

Comment: What he really ought to do is add a common class `element` to `#element-one`, `-two` and `-three`, then select `$('.element .object')` instead.

Comment: @Blazemonger That is true

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't realize find() did that. Thanks to both of you. I have fixed it with a common class :)